# Calculate year difference between 2 dates with 0 year as 1 year

Tags: mysql, intervals, timestampdiff

I have 2 dates to compare so I can count years between both date. If days is less than 365 days then I use `interval` to make it as 1 year. However I have problem if both date is similar in day for example `2019-10-15` to `2020-10-15` will be displayed as 2 years when I want it to be displayed as 1 year. Here is my code with not the result I want:

```
SELECT
  TIMESTAMPDIFF(
    YEAR,
    '2019-10-15',
    '2020-10-15' + INTERVAL 1 YEAR
  ) AS `year`
FROM
  dob
```

Result:

[image]

What I want is:

`2019-10-15` to `2020-10-14` = `1 year`

`2019-10-15` to `2020-10-15` = `1 year`

`2019-10-15` to `2020-10-16` = `2 year`

How can I achieved that? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this do what you want? It seems you're only one day out from the expected output so I just subtracted a day.

```
SELECT 
TIMESTAMPDIFF
( YEAR, '2019-10-15',
 '2020-10-15' 
+ INTERVAL 1 YEAR
- INTERVAL 1 DAY ) 
AS `year` 
FROM dob
```

Comment: yes it is. I didn't know you could add another `interval` in there. Thank you very much.